# how can I track users who try to execute procedures with no permissions

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL server 2012 and I want to get alerts when user is trying to execute stored procedure without permissions.
what is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use an extended events session:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION test_error
ON SERVER
ADD EVENT sqlserver.error_reported
(
    ACTION (sqlserver.sql_text, sqlserver.tsql_stack, sqlserver.database_id, sqlserver.username)
    WHERE ([error_number] = 229)
)
ADD TARGET package0.ring_buffer;
ALTER EVENT SESSION test_error ON SERVER STATE = START;
```

Then to view the data, something like:

```
SELECT CAST(st.target_data AS XML)
FROM sys.dm_xe_session_targets AS st
JOIN sys.dm_xe_sessions AS s
    ON s.address = st.event_session_address
WHERE s.name = 'test_error';
```

I leave it as an exercise to the reader to shred the XML for whatever you think is relevant. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's an idea, but I think it could work:

Create a log table, place the T_SQL of the specific stored procedure in a TRY/CATCH block and log all failed attempts. 
Make sure an attempt can fail based on permissions and write the user data (CURRENT_USER, SYSTEM_USER, etc.) to the log table in the catch. 
Then create an AFTER INSERT trigger on the log table to send a database mail.